# Вопрос о итераторах

Tags: c++

В каких случаях программа при отладке выдаёт ошибку: **vector iterator not dereferencable** и как ее, *примерно*, можно исправить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636941/vector-iterator-not-dereferencable-in-for-loop

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 2):

Такая ошибка может происходить когда итератор невалидный (`end()` или контейнер был изменен).
Используйте валидные итераторы.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: При **сборке** такое может отследить?...

Comment: Я немного неправильно выразился - при отладке, там исключение выбрасывается.